# azure map store locator with custom map

Tags: azure-maps

I want to implement store locator, where i dont want to upload store location when user comes to the page.

I started with this [e.g](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/tutorial-create-store-locator) from MSFT website

e.g. works but I have 1 million POI (Specific to my business use-case), so doing it live for multiple customer seems to be a overkill. when all of them are suppose to see same set of POI.

I was able to upload all the POIs via offline channel using this [e.g.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/dataset/createpreview). call was successful and I got UDID for the resource.

but now i am confused, how do i refer to this UDID in store locator e.g and completely skip this call => datasource.importDataFromUrl(storeLocationGeoJsonUrl)

Answer (score 0):

For larger datasets you should upload the data into a database in Azure and create a simple service to query a subset of the data. SQL Azure has built in spatial query support. A simple Azure function can be used to create a web service. A simple bounding box query is easy to achieve using based SQL queries or the built in spatial capabilities. Here are some resources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-sql-server

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/build-api-azure-functions/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-serverless-api

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/seasons-of-serverless-challenge-1-azure-functions-and-azure-sql-database-serverless/

If you want to be able to visualize all points on the map, you can convert your data into a vector tile service and pull it in using the VectorTileSource class. This is a lot more work than the first approach, but creates a more fluid solution.

Comment: then the question comes to my mind. what will be use of (create dataset api)=> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/dataset/createpreview  when I cant refer to it from UI/web.

Comment: That is currently used for Azure Maps Creator (indoor maps) in Autocad format. In the future we are looking at potentially supporting other spatial file formats, but not something that is supported at the moment. There may be a way to inject custom spatial data if formatted as building info, but given that this service is still in preview, doing something like this would be at risk of breaking.